# Return a string from a function using pointer

Tags: c, string, function

I am trying to read a string in a function and then return it to the main program and print it there.
The problem is that when I print the string in the main program it appears that there is not data in the string array

The code I wrote is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getString(){
    char buff[10]; //String Array to be used within the function
    char *pbuff = &buff; //Pointer to the address
    printf("Enter the name: ");
    scanf("%s", buff);
    return pbuff; //Returns the pointer to the array
}

int main(){
    char MyString[10]; //string in the main program
    char *pMyString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // Allocation for the memory for the pointer


    pMyString = &MyString; //pointer to the array


    *pMyString = getString();

    printf("%s", pMyString);

}
```

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Combiler does not give any errors When i print the array it prints random characters which I guess it's because there is nothing allocated

Comment: @TomisAristidou: on the contrary, compiling with `gcc -Wall ...` gives four very helpful warnings pointing out the error of your ways.